# Spring Boot/Batch with multiple @Configuration classes not instantiating bean (or loading properties)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, spring-batch

So first, apologies if this seems to similar to other problems - I've looked, tried the proposed solutions, and none have solved the problems. First the sanitized code...

```
package com.mine.batchMain;
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
//...
public static void main(String[] args) {
//....
}
}

package com.mine.batchMain;
//...
import com.min.batchMain.firstSteps.FirstStepConfigHolder;
//...

@Configuration 
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfigurer {
//....
@Autowired
private FirstStepConfigHolder firstStep;
//...
@Bean
public Step defineFirstStep() {
return stepBuilder.get("First Step")
.chunk<MyPOJO, MyPOJO>(batchSize)
.readerfirstStep.fetcher())
.writer(firstStep.extracter())
.listener(firstStep.listen())
.build();
}
//....
}

package com.mine.batchMain.firstSteps;
//...
import com.mine.batchMain.common.MyRepo;
import com.mine.batchMain.firstSteps.DocFetcher;
//...

@Configuration
@EnableJPARepositories
public class FirstStepConfigHolder {
//....
@Value("${myapp.dbUrl}")
String dbUrl;
@Value("${myapp.dbSchema}")
String dbSchema;
@Value("${myapp.dbUser}")
String dbUser;
@Value("${myapp.encDbPass}")
String encryptDbPass;
@Value("${myapp.dbDriver}")
String dbDriver;
@Value("${myapp.maxDocSize}")
String maxDocSize;
@Value("${myapp.maxNumDocs}")
String maxNumDocs;

@Bean
public DocFetcher fetcher() {
    log.trace("Creating DocFetcher.")
    return new DocFetcher(myDb());
}
@Bean
public MyRepo myDb() {
    log.trace("Creating repo.");
    MyRepo retDb = new MyRepo(myDataSource());
    retDb.setMaxNumDocs(Integer.valueOf(maxNumDocs));
    retDb.setMaxDocSize(Integer.valueOf(maxDocSize));
    log.debug("Confirming db class state:"+retDb.toString());
    return retDb;
}
private DataSource myDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource retDs = new DriverManagerDataSource(dbUrl, dbUser, decrypt(encryptDbPass));
    retDs.setDriverClassName(dbDriver);
    return retDs;
}
```

}

The problems/symptoms are these:
1) MyRepo is not picking up maxDocSize and maxNumDocs. (Logging shows the defaults)
2) Logging shows the trace call to "Creating DocFetcher", but not to "Creating repo.", nor is it showing the debug of the Repo state.

Which is frustrating, as according to what I know & understand, it *should* be picking them up. What am I missing and/or not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your **BatchConfigurer.java** file should be in the same package as your **MainApplication.java** file .

or,

Import **[BatchConfigurer.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kQAC.png)** in your **MainApplication.java** file.

Check this image for reference

Comment: It is. I've edited the code to show the package relationships.

Comment: Not an issue, just add 
    
      @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mine"})

in your MyApplication file

It will definately work .

Comment: I have already done so. To no result. Also, according to the documentation, since everything's under the same package, a) ComponentScan should pick everything up by default. b) I shouldn't even need to explicitly declare ComponentScan.